# Is there any CLI or GUI client for Sphinx searchd? Something like mysql query browser

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

I need some tool which would allow me to run Sphinx queries. Sphinx provides `search`, a command line program which does the thing. However, `search` is reading Sphinx files and I need something what would connect to searchd instead. Do you know any tools I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you guys from Sphinx forum! There is "api" directory in [source tarball](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads.html). It contains test.php and test.py - two tiny programs which do this job. There are also test2.php and test2.py, I haven't checked them.